# Wrong month (February) - DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php

The date conversion from string returns wrong values for the 2nd month (February):

```
$dtformat = 'Y-m-01';
$curDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '1996-02');
print_r($curDate);
$dt     = $curDate->format($dtformat);
echo $dt."\n";
```

Instead of "1996-02-01", it returns "1996-03-01". This is the `$currDate` array:

```
DateTime Object ( 
    [date] => 1996-03-02 01:19:01 
    [timezone_type] => 3 
    [timezone] => America/New_York 
)
```

All other months work fine. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a bug according to this [post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#109881).

**Cause:** When we don't provide date to `createFromFormat` it will take as today's date by default. So in this case it will be `1996-02-31` which does not exist & thus it will take a next month.

**Solution:** Need to provide day to avoid such scenario.

```
$date = "2011-02";
echo $date."\n";
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$date."-01");
echo $d->format("Y-m");
```

Comment: Yes, seems to be a better way than adjusting each 2nd month

Answer (score 6):

Try with this code:

```
$curDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m', '1996-02');
```

The [manual explains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> !     
> Resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timezone information) to the Unix Epoch

Comment: '!Y-m' would work. '!' resets all fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fraction and timzone information) to the Unix Epoch. If you put it after the year, the year will be reset to 1970.

Comment: This helped me with `DateTime::createFromFormat("Ym", "200006")` is _2000-07-01 16:47:26.000000_ while  `DateTime::createFromFormat("!Ym", "200006")` is _2000-06-01 00:00:00.000000_  -  **BIG  difference**

Comment: [datetimeimmutable.createfromformat | php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php)