# PHP: Weird bug in DateTime::createFromFormat?

Tags: php, datetime

So this appears to only be happening today, but this does not seem right to me. I encountered it converting dates from one representation to another, I was not having this problem on other days.

```
Interactive shell
php > print_r(DateTime::createFromFormat('n Y','5 2017')->format('YM'));
2017May
php > print_r(DateTime::createFromFormat('n Y','6 2017')->format('YM'));
2017Jul
```

Am I missing something? My expected output for the second statement is "2017Jun"

This is a duplicate of [Wrong month (February) - DateTime::createFromFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473817/wrong-month-february-datetimecreatefromformat#21473903)

Comment: Since you're not specifying the day it's using todays date, the 31st... 31st of June rolls over to the 1st of July. Set the day to the 1st or something if you don't care about it.

Comment: oh good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473817/wrong-month-february-datetimecreatefromformat#21473903

Answer (score 0):

If you do not give it a day it uses today's date as seed.

Since 31/6/17 does not exist it rolls over to the next month.